# Generate Graphs Using xlsx4j?

Tags: apache-poi, docx4j

Please can i have a good answer for my question :

**I need to generate a docx file with editable graphs**

I wanna know if i can use xlsx4j to generate charts then, i'll put them in docx using (OLE objects) ?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an XLSX (or use xlsx4j).

Instead, just create the chart part, as explained at http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/generate-complex-word-document-t2542.html#p8742

Please don't cross post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Can you provide a simple (to explain  using Part objects into docx files) example please, i can't create the chart part in docx file.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Chart chartPart = new org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.DrawingML.Chart();  then addTargetPart